# How to ensure that the solution to an optimization problem is a probability distribution?

Tags: probability, optimization, constrained-optimization

How to ensure that the solution to an optimisation problem is a probability distribution?

For example, assume we minimise over a distribution $p$. We must ensure that $\int p(x) \,dx=1 $.

But why don't we also have to ensure (e.g. in the Lagrangian) that $p(x) \geq 0$?

Comment: To the people who closed this:  it's not about $p > 1$, it's about enforcing $p \geq 0$ when determining $p$ using some optimization routine.

Comment: The inherent misconception reflected by this notation is that "$p(x)$" is a probability.  It is not: it's a *density.*  That's the issue addressed by the duplicate (cc @jbowman). A density can be arbitrarily large, even infinite.  For discrete distributions we may interpret $p(x)$ as probabilities, but then their positivity and the summation-to-unity requirement mathematically guarantee all values are $1$ or less, anyway, so it would be redundant to introduce that constraint.

Comment: @whuber - I think the question could be rephrased as:  if I'm trying to find a probability distribution that is optimal in some way, how do I ensure the function I find is actually a probability distribution?  It has to integrate to one; why don't we also have to (for example) have Lagrange multipliers to ensure it's $\geq 0$ everywhere?

Comment: @jbowman Thanks--I see how it can be read that way.  I didn't do so because I cannot imagine any instance where the non-negativity constraints are ignored.  It would be good to see an example.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but it still doesn't clear up the main difficulty: can you supply any example of such an optimization that does *not* incorporate that non-negativity constraint?

Comment: @whuber - Thanks! Yes, assume you want to find a distribution that maximizes an objective. In cases such as entropy maximization the constraint $0 \leq p(X)$ is already incorporated in the objective in the $\log p(x)$. However, my question relates to problems e.g. $\max\limits_{p(X)} \int_{\mathcal{X}} p(x) f(x, \cdot) \,dx$ where we constrain the distribution to integrate to one, but we do not explicitly consider  $0 \leq p(X)$.

Comment: My point is that I have *never* seen an account that ignored the non-negativity constraint, for if it did, it would be incorrect.  Thus, I am sceptical that your question refers to anything real or relevant.